# Missing arguments and type errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was instructed to run the current code and understand the error message and change only one line of the function **bs** and fix the error I can kind of understand what the error message is saying, but I don't know how 
to fix it or where the actual problem is occurring in the function bs

```
def bs(L, item, left, right):
    if right is None:
        right = len(L)
    if right - left == 0:
        return False
    if right - left == 1:
        return L[left] == item
    median = (right + left)//2
    if item < L[median]:
        return bs(L, item, left, median)
    else:
        return bs(L, item, median, right)

L = [i for i in range(10)]
for i in range(20):
    print(bs(L, i))
```

The error is the following

```
    print(bs(L, i))
    TypeError: bs() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'left' and 'right'
```

Comment: The error is pretty much self explanatory, what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: You need to supply two more arguments to the function. The function takes 4 arguments

Comment: I don't understand how I could fix the function bs without changing more than one line. I thought the error was in the print statement where it is missing left and right, print(bs(L, i)) but that wasn't it,

Comment: Do you know what the function `bs` is supposed to be doing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010660/binary-search-implementation-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Simply, assign default values to your parameters:(Thanks to **trentcl**)

```
def bs(L, item, left = 0, right = None):
...
```

**BEFORE EDIT**

If you want to call function like `bs(L, i)`, you need default values in your function. `left` must be 0 and `right` must be `len(L)` by default, but as far as I know, you can't do this in function definition. Change these lines:

```
sentinel = object()
def bs(L, item, left = 0, right = sentinel):
    if right is sentinel:
        right = len(L)
...
```

[Sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) is used as a flag or dummy data as usual. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575371/6900838) is an example. If it confuses your mind and you don't want to use it, just use a special integer like `-1`:

```
def bs(L, item, left = 0, right = -1):
    if right is -1:
        right = len(L)
...
```

Comment: The `if right is sentinel` clause is in the original code. The sentinel value is `None`.

Comment: @trentcl You're right, assigning default values to parameters is enough